# Knockout: Unable to bind change in quantity to total cost in shopping cart

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout JS and I am working on a simple shopping cart. The user enters in the name, price, and quantity of an item.

That information outputs into the 'Items in Cart' area, an observable array, and the total price is displayed under that.

The user can change the quantity in the 'Items in Cart' area, but that change doesn't change the total cost.

How do I bind a change in quantity in the 'Items in Cart' area to the total cost?

Thank you in advance.

```js
var viewModel = {
  newItemName: ko.observable(),
  newItemPrice: ko.observable(0),
  newItemQuantity: ko.observable(1),


  addNewItem: function() {
    var newItem = {
      name: this.newItemName(),
      price: this.newItemPrice(),
      quantity: this.newItemQuantity()
    };

    this.itemsInCart.push(newItem);
    this.newItemName("");
    this.newItemPrice(0);
    this.newItemQuantity(1);
  },

  removeItem: function() {
    viewModel.itemsInCart.remove(this);
  },

  itemsInCart: ko.observableArray([{
    newItemQuantity()
  }])
};

viewModel.addNewItemEnabled = ko.pureComputed(function()

  {
    var name = this.newItemName(),
      price = this.newItemPrice(),
      quantity = ko.observable(viewModel.newItemQuantity(1));

    return name && name.length;
  },
  viewModel);

viewModel.getTotalCost = ko.computed(function()

  {
    var total = 0;
    arr = viewModel.itemsInCart();
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      total += arr[i].price * arr[i].quantity;
    return total;
  },

  viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
<hr />
<h3>Add New Item</h3>
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: newItemName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
<br />
<label>Unit Price:</label>
<input type="number" min="0" step="0.25" data-bind="value: newItemPrice, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
<br />
<label>Quantity:</label>
<input type="number" min="1" step="1" data-bind="value: newItemQuantity, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
<br />
<button data-bind="click: addNewItem, enable: addNewItemEnabled">Add Item</button>
<hr />
<h3>Items in Cart</h3>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemsInCart">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td>$<span data-bind="text: price"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" data-bind="value: quantity, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h3 data-bind="visible: getTotalCost() > 0 "> Your total will be $<span data-bind="text: getTotalCost"></span></h3>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4atrw2g/8/

Comment: I realized I made a mistake in in the ko.obesrvable array, which I've changed in http://jsfiddle.net/b4atrw2g/10/. 

I've been at this for a while and am a bit loopy. I have knockout fatigue. And I just ordered some Chinese food, which won't help anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*point to remember:* while dealing with ko  `if something is not getting updated means it is not a observable`

Here in you case `var newItem = {` you are simply assigning rather you should assign the values to observable like below

```
var newItem = {
            name: ko.observable(this.newItemName()),
            price: ko.observable(this.newItemPrice()),
            quantity: ko.observable(this.newItemQuantity())
    };
```

Modified fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/b4atrw2g/11/)**

Just in case if you are looking for neat and clean one and most importantly a complete`ko` one check this fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/74dh736s/12/)**

Comment: Wow, thanks @super cool, this works perfectly. I knew it was an observable issue, but I get lost in the syntax I think, which is why I'm re-doing a tutorial on JS syntax. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at this part of the Knockout documentation for guidance: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections.

In particular, watch how they make the **Total surcharge** change when the **Meal** type changes on each row.  It's essentially the same thing you're trying to do with your quantity for each item in your cart.

Also, I noticed that you set up your view model as a var.  I usually make mine a function, like this:

```
function myViewModel(){
  // cool view model code here
}
```

Then, when you're ready to apply bindings, you do this:

```
ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

The big thing I've noticed when working with Knockout is that one needs to pay very close attention to how parentheses are used with the observable arrays and other bindable model properties.  For example, there's a big difference between

```
this.myObservableArray().push(item);
```

and

```
this.myObservableArray.push(item);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this @Jeff Mahoney, I think setting it up as a function would've been better too, but it was given to me in this way and I didn't feel comfortable enough to change the format of it. Thanks again!